# How to read a nested, non-array JSON in java?

Tags: java, json

I've a JSON file with:

```
 "items": [
  {
   (...)
   "volumeInfo": {
    (...)
    "readingModes": {
     "text": true,
     "image": true
    },
    (...)
  }
```

How do I access 'image' and 'text' in "readingModes"? I've tried both

```
JSONArray readingModes = volumeInfo.optJSONArray("readingModes");
```

which worked for data with squared bracket, but in this case returns nulls

and

```
JSONObject readingModes = gobj.getJSONObject("readingModes");
```

which returns error - JSONObject["readingModes"] not found, where gobj is accessed:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray items = jobj.getJSONArray("items");
Iterator i = items.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
{
    JSONObject gobj = (JSONObject) i.next();
(...)
}
```

Comment: Is readingModes in `volumeInfo`?

Comment: please fix the json example
is volumeInfo contains "readingModes"?

Comment: Yes, it's in there.

Comment: so you missing the parse of volumeInfo:
JSONObject volumeInfo = gobj.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
 before 
JSONArray readingModes = volumeInfo.optJSONArray("readingModes");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray items = jobj.getJSONArray("items");
Iterator i = items.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
{
    JSONObject gobj = (JSONObject) i.next();
    JSONObject volumeInfo = gobj.getJSONObject('volumeInfo');
    JSONObject readingModes = volumeInfo.getJSONObject('readingModes');
(...)
}
```

According to your JSON you need to do this.
Since `readingModes` is in `volumeInfo`, you first need to get JSON object of volumeInfo in order to access `readingModes`.

Comment: @Ambu accept the answer if it helped you si that other people can know which one is correct